# Alterar a cor do site ao clicar no botão contraste

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando um site desenvolvido em Bootstrap e ele terá acessibilidade. Consegui colocar o aumentar e diminuir a fonte, porém não estou conseguindo criar o contraste, ou seja, ao clicar no botão **Contraste**, o site ficar escuro com fontes brancas. Tentei com o código abaixo, mas não consegui progredir no Javascript.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="CONTRASTE" onclick='contraste()'><i class="fa fa-adjust" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contraste</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 function contraste(){
         document.bgColor = '#000';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui essa solução:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cor fundo</title>
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css-teste/escuro.css" title="2">
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="css-teste/claro.css" title="1">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/alterar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="click">Contraste</button>

<br><br>

Conteúdo do site

</body>
</html>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       if($.cookie("contrast-bar")) {setActiveStyleSheet($.cookie("contrast-bar"));}

       $('#click').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               if ( getActiveStyleSheet() == '1') {
                       setActiveStyleSheet('2');
               } else {
                       setActiveStyleSheet('1');
               }
       });
});

function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
       var i, a, main;
       for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {

               if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
                       a.disabled = true;
                       if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
               }
       }
       $.cookie("contrast-bar",title, {expires: 365, path: '/'});
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
       var i, a;
       for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
               if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
       }
       return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
       var i, a;
       for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
               if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) return a.getAttribute("title");
       }
       return null;
}

jQuery.cookie = function(name, value, options) {
if (typeof value != 'undefined') { // name and value given, set cookie
options = options || {};
if (value === null) {
value = '';
options.expires = -1;
}
var expires = '';
if (options.expires && (typeof options.expires == 'number' || options.expires.toUTCString)) {
var date;
if (typeof options.expires == 'number') {
date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (options.expires * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
} else {
date = options.expires;
}
expires = '; expires=' + date.toUTCString(); // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
}
// CAUTION: Needed to parenthesize options.path and options.domain
// in the following expressions, otherwise they evaluate to undefined
// in the packed version for some reason...
var path = options.path ? '; path=' + (options.path) : '';
var domain = options.domain ? '; domain=' + (options.domain) : '';
var secure = options.secure ? '; secure' : '';
document.cookie = [name, '=', encodeURIComponent(value), expires, path, domain, secure].join('');
} else { // only name given, get cookie
var cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
// Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
break;
}
}
}
return cookieValue;
}
};// JavaScript Document
```

**escuro.css**

```
body{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

**claro.css**

```
 body{
      background-color: #FFF;
      color: #00F;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

O código que você escreveu apenas seta a proriedade do `document` de um jeito que tende a não afetar a página.

Você poderia fazer o que deseja com o seguinte código:

```
function contraste(){
     $("body")
         .css("background-color", "black")
         .css("color", "white");
}
```

Note que em CSS, `color` em geral afeta a cor do texto dentro de um elemento ou de seus filhos.

Mas ainda assim, isso pode não ser efetivo. Caso algum elemento tenha uma regra CSS definida para a cor do texto, ela se sobreporá à cor definida pela função acima. Você teria que alterar os outros elementos também. Mesmo para um site simples o esforço tende a crescer e ficar inviável muito rápido se você quiser controlar tudo via Javascript.

O ideal é você ter duas folhas de estilo - uma de alto contraste e outra não. Assim você pode estilizar não apenas o texto, mas o fundo  e os detalhes de todos os elementos da sua página de uma forma mais confortável e acessível para quem tem problemas de visão.

Daí você controla qual folha de estilo vai carregar a partir de alguma variável de sessão (ou configuração do usuário). Você vai precisar codificar no backend também para alcançar esse objetivo.

Comment: Boa explicação Renan, eu estava pensando em colocar na minha resposta,  o código da pergunta muda o cor de fundo do `document`, mas o problema dele deve ser todos os outros elementos que permanecem com seu respectivo estilo.

Comment: Olá Renan. Entendi. No caso de eu querer usar duas folhas de estilo. Como eu faria essa troca usando apenas um botão?

Comment: Encontrei nesse site uma solução, mas usa-se 02 links. Gostaria de usar apenas 01. http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/alternatecss.php

Comment: @Fox.11 eu sempre prefiro fazer a mudança no backend. Você precisa usar algo como PHP, ou ASP.NET.